# How different is SHA-512/224 when compared to SHA-512?

Tags: hash, openssl, sha-2, sha-512

I understood from the [NIST SHS specifications (FIPS 140-4)](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.180-4.pdf) that the difference between SHA-512 and SHA-512/224 the two differences are the initial hash value and the final result truncation

I changed the initial hash value of SHA-512 to that one of SHA-512/224 as specified in the SHS specifications and then built the CAVS tests. Then I started testing against the [copied CAVP test vector](https://pastebin.com/wivUc5eH).

Lets consider the first case:

```
Len = 0
Msg = 00
MD = d14a028c2a3a2bc9476102bb288234c415a2b01f828ea62ac5b3e42f
```

But the result I am obtaining for the above input is:

```
SHA512/224 digest
     6ed0dd02806fa89e25de060c19d3ac86cabb87d6a0ddd05c333b84f4
```

Lets consider the second case:

```
Len = 8
Msg = 84
MD = 3cd36921df5d6963e73739cf4d20211e2d8877c19cff087ade9d0e3a
```

But the result I am obtaining for the above input is:

```
SHA512/224 digest
     8f8fdcb3f617a2d809b3132860b02fee00bdd927d541d42073dd12e7
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation of the algorithms seems to correct, but in the test cases the vectors are those of SHA224. Here are my results:

```
C:\TMP\0
    SHA224: d14a028c2a3a2bc9476102bb288234c415a2b01f828ea62ac5b3e42f
    SHA512: cf83e1357eefb8bdf1542850d66d8007d620e4050b5715dc83f4a921d36ce9ce47d0d13c5d85f2b0ff8318d2877eec2f63b931bd47417a81a538327af927da3e
SHA512/224: 6ed0dd02806fa89e25de060c19d3ac86cabb87d6a0ddd05c333b84f4

C:\TMP\8
    SHA224: 3cd36921df5d6963e73739cf4d20211e2d8877c19cff087ade9d0e3a
    SHA512: f180d4243a77ba2b31456286cb55ac765117bdac22b8c3d4f7cdc9dd5b7ba49222fc91da2cddcd81c6ad97d18d562a5727bc7660dc8b7ce05a06976e7ad10bbb
SHA512/224: 8f8fdcb3f617a2d809b3132860b02fee00bdd927d541d42073dd12e7
```

Comment: I am new to these cryptographic algorithms so in NIST Site they have not specified any specific test cases  for SHA512/224 and SHA512/256. So i thought it might take the test vectors of SHA224. Can you please let me know whether any other site provide test vector to verify my algorithm(SHA512/224)?

Comment: As a start, use the link from FIPS 180.4 A2 
(http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/examples.html).
There are a lot of test cases for all hash algorithms, especially 
http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/documents/Examples/SHA512_224.pdf (with intermediate results)

Answer (score 3):

As stated by [FIPS 186-4 (6.6)](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.180-4.pdf#page=31) The only two differences between SHA-512 and SHA-512/224 are the eight 64-bit words used for initialization, given by [FIPS 186-4 (5.3.6.1)](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.180-4.pdf#page=22); and result truncation to the first 224 bits of the 512-bit result: $H_0^{(N)}$, $H_1^{(N)}$, $H_2^{(N)}$ each 64-bit, and the high-order 32 bits of $H_3^{(N)}$.

I suggest to start by checking the SHA-512 implementation pass test vectors; then implement the truncation, and test; then change the initialization value, and test.

[epilogue: that was the test vectors, see [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/48005/555)]

Comment: I followed the same procedure.But its not working for 512/224 or 512/256